# Linking c++ against boost in an R package

Tags: boost, graph, makefile, package, rcpp

I'm making an R package on data flows in networks. For speed, some of the code is written in C++, and with my own implementation of graph algorithms. I'd like to re-write my code to use the Boost Graph Library.

What would I need to put in the Makevars file to set the compiler/linker option to find boost? Sorry, I'm not very good with Make.

I'm working in a Linux environment

Yes I looked at RBGL, but did not find a makefile in that package

If it matters, I'm using Rcpp to interface the R and C++ code

Answer (score 4):

It's not that hard.  By default, every Rcpp package has a default `src/Makevars` which contains

```
## Use the R_HOME indirection to support installations of multiple R version
PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"`
```

where the library for Rcpp itself is found dynamically by asking R.  You just expand this and add

```
-lboost_graph
```

(and/or maybe the parallel or mt variants).  If you they are installed in an unusual place, also add `-L...` flags.  Dito for PKG_CFLAGS for header locations.

That's about it. See the `Writing R Extensions` manual about more details on building R packages.